# custom property visual studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a custom property in vb.net with Visual Studio 2012, but i have problem setting my custom property both in design time and run time. This was not a problem with Visual Studio 2010. It seems like a bug, but maybe i have forgot to turn some options on or off or have i forgot something in my code?

```
Public Class MyCustomButton
  Inherits Button

  Private m_MyBackgroundColor As Color
  Public Property MyBackgroundColor As Color
    Get
      Return m_MyBackgroundColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
      value = m_MyBackgroundColor
      Me.BackColor = m_MyBackgroundColor
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Your setter appears to be wrong. You're overwriting the `value` parameter with the current value of your field, instead of vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change setter to this:

```
Set(value As Color)
  m_MyBackgroundColor = value 'swapped value and m_MyBackgroundColor
  Me.BackColor = m_MyBackgroundColor
End Set
```

Comment: To many late nights! The answer was easy:
Changing value = m_MyBackgroundColor to 
m_MyBackgroundColor = value solved the problem.

Comment: @user2196583: I guess I too need some sleep, cause I did not notice this issue until now. Congrats on finding it yourself. :)

Comment: @TinTin: I updated my answer to be relevant in light of your recent discovery. Hope you don't mind. :)